# ASP.NET MVC - DisplayFormat attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, editorfor, dataformat

In my model i've the MyDate property that has datetime type.
I sign the property with the DisplayFormat attribute in this mode:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}")]
public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
```

in my view:

```
...
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Evento.MyDate)%>
...
```

why if the value of property is '2011-05-03 14:47', in my view (into EditorFor) i see '03/05/2011 02.47' ?

The DataFormatString is correct!

thanks so much for reply

Alberto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the format string of `{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}` will output as `03/05/2011 02.47`. You're seeing what I would expect to see.

**UPDATE:**
To get the 24 hour notation you can use `{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}` with the uppercase `HH` to designate the hour.

Comment: my problem is that the time is not formatted correctly. I expected  14:47 no 02.47...

Comment: @Alberto Rubini: Ah, I see.  I've updated my answer to reflect what you're trying to accomplish.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `:` is a reserved character indicating the time separator for the given culture which in your case might happen to be the `.` character. You want:

```
DataFormatString = @"{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm}"
```

You probably might also want to use `HH` which is the 24 hour format instead of `hh`.